# Multiple joins error in group by when I use SUM function

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

I'm getting this error:

```
Column 'MDR.dbo.nav_BG$Location.Name' is invalid in the select list because 
it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

He wants from me to add all my fields in group by but this is incorrect.

```
DECLARE @date datetime2 = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
SELECT   
[Source Document ID]        AS Source
,Location.Name              AS Address
,[Item No_]                 AS No
,[Document No_]             AS Document
,Item.[No_ 2]               AS No2
,MN.Name                    AS Brand
,SUM([Quantity Requested])  AS Qty,
CASE WHEN qty > 20 THEN  'No' ELSE 'Yes'  END AS Priority
,[Created On]               AS Date


FROM [MDR].[dbo].[nav_BG$AWHM_Document_Line] AS DocLine
JOIN [MDR].[dbo].[nav_BG$Item] AS Item ON DocLine.[Item No_] = Item.[No_]
JOIN [MDR].[dbo].[nav_BG$Location] AS Location ON DocLine.[Source Document ID] = Location.Code
JOIN [MDR].[dbo].[nav_BG$Manufacturer] AS MN ON Item.[Manufacturer Code] = MN.Code

WHERE [Location Code] = 'XXX'
AND   [Document Type] = 'XXX'
AND   [From Zone Code] = 'XXX'
AND   (DATEPART(yy, [Created On]) = YEAR(@date)
AND    DATEPART(mm, [Created On]) = MONTH(@date)
AND    DATEPART(dd, [Created On]) = DAY(@date))
GROUP BY [Source Document ID]
ORDER BY [Created On]
```

Expected result would be the `SUM([Quantity Requested]) group by [Source Document ID]`.

How to use only one group by `[Source Document ID]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to use an aggregate function, you normally need to specify all your non-aggregated columns (like `Location.Name`) in the `GROUP BY` clause.  Otherwise, you can't return them in your query.

If you want to return non-aggregated fields and also include an aggregate, you need to use a window function:

`SUM([Quantity Requested]) OVER(PARTITION BY [Source Document ID])`

If your DBMS supports it, it would look like:

```sql
SELECT   
[Source Document ID]        AS Source
,Location.Name              AS Address
,[Item No_]                 AS No
,[Document No_]             AS Document
,Item.[No_ 2]               AS No2
,MN.Name                    AS Brand
,SUM([Quantity Requested]) OVER(PARTITION BY [Source Document ID])  AS Qty,
CASE WHEN qty > 20 THEN  'No' ELSE 'Yes'  END AS Priority
,[Created On]               AS Date

FROM [MDR].[dbo].[nav_BG$AWHM_Document_Line] AS DocLine
JOIN [MDR].[dbo].[nav_BG$Item] AS Item ON DocLine.[Item No_] = Item.[No_]
JOIN [MDR].[dbo].[nav_BG$Location] AS Location ON DocLine.[Source Document ID] = Location.Code
JOIN [MDR].[dbo].[nav_BG$Manufacturer] AS MN ON Item.[Manufacturer Code] = MN.Code

WHERE [Location Code] = 'XXX'
AND   [Document Type] = 'XXX'
AND   [From Zone Code] = 'XXX'
AND   (DATEPART(yy, [Created On]) = YEAR(@date)
AND    DATEPART(mm, [Created On]) = MONTH(@date)
AND    DATEPART(dd, [Created On]) = DAY(@date))
-- GROUP BY [Source Document ID]
ORDER BY [Created On]
```

This will let you return the detail rows along with the `SUM()` calculated over each `[Source Document ID]` group.